# Two things which can go together

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word, or words, which would appropriately convey that two items can go together. As an example, a Sword and Shield. I am using this for a game that I am making, and I have items which can go in the off-hand slot of the inventory. So, as an example, if you have a one-handed sword, axe, or mace equipped in the main hand, you can equip a shield in the off-hand slot, because these things are, as I'm currently calling it, ***unifiable***. Other such examples are a Bow and Quiver. However, with a Bow equipped, you cannot equip a shield, because a Bow is not ***unifiable*** with a shield. Another example is a Staff or Wand, which are both ***unifiable*** with a Tome. Again though, a Tome cannot be equipped with a Sword, Mace, or Axe, etc.

Sentence example:

```
"You can equip a Shield with a Sword, because they're _____."
"You cannot equip a Tome with a Bow, because they're not ____."
```

It may be unnecessary to post this, but here is the coding example of this concept written out. I just want a better naming mechanism for the function:

```
        public static bool IsUnifiableWith(this ItemType itemType, ItemType other)
        {
            switch (itemType)
            {
                case ItemType.Bow:
                    return other == ItemType.Quiver;
                case ItemType.Dagger:
                    return other == ItemType.Dagger;
                case ItemType.Fist:
                    return other == ItemType.Fist;
                case ItemType.Instrument:
                    return other == ItemType.Score;
                case ItemType.OneHandedAxe:
                case ItemType.OneHandedMace:
                case ItemType.OneHandedSword:
                    return
                        other == ItemType.Shield ||
                        other == ItemType.OneHandedSword ||
                        other == ItemType.OneHandedAxe ||
                        other == ItemType.OneHandedMace;
                case ItemType.Scythe:
                    return other == ItemType.Phylactery;
                case ItemType.Staff:
                case ItemType.Wand:
                    return other == ItemType.Tome;
                case ItemType.Phylactery:
                    return other == ItemType.Scythe;
                case ItemType.Quiver:
                    return other == ItemType.Bow;
                case ItemType.Score:
                    return other == ItemType.Instrument;
                case ItemType.Shield:
                    return
                        other == ItemType.OneHandedAxe ||
                        other == ItemType.OneHandedMace ||
                        other == ItemType.OneHandedSword;
                case ItemType.Tome:
                    return other == ItemType.Staff || other == ItemType.Wand;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
```

What other words could convey a matching of items, as I have mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

Those things are said to be *compatible* (or not):

> (of two things) able to exist or occur together without problems or conflict.

<sub>(source: [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/compatible))</sub>

These things can be abstract definitions or concrete items. It's widely used when talking about electronics or computer software, but it works just as well as for 'primitive' technology.

Comment: Complementary ?

Answer (score 1):

***Pairable***

*Capable of being paired with something else*

This comes from the verb *pair*:

> **Pair**
>
> to make or become one of a pair:
>
> *Famous paintings have been paired with poems by Sandburg, Angelou, and others.*
>
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/pair

A sword can be paired with a shield.

A sword cannot be paired with a bow.  They are not pairable.